# Page shift when showing fixed 'modal' div

Tags: css, modal-dialog, marionette

So I've built my own custom modal box in backbone.marionette, but I'm running into the issue that every time I `show()` the modal, my page shifts down about half an inch. Very annoying. Anyone have ideas how to account for this or to fix it?

Here's my `#modal` and `.overlay` css:

```
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index: 1002;
    width: 70%;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - If I set the modal's `top` property to `0` and give it a `margin-top` of whatever, then there's no annoying offset. Here's the final css I landed on:

```
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    z-index: 1002;
    width: 70%;
}
```